# Need help understanding NYS 2023 ballot proposals

Tags: united-states, referendum, new-york

The [ballot proposals](https://www.nycvotes.org/meet-the-candidates/ballot-proposals/) state:

> A. The proposed amendment to Article 8, section 4 of the Constitution
> removes the special constitutional debt limitation now placed on small
> city school districts, so they will be treated the same as all other
> school districts. Shall the proposed amendment be approved?
>
> B. The proposed amendment to Article 8, section 5 of the Constitution
> extends for ten years the authority of counties, cities, towns, and
> villages to remove from their constitutional debt limits debt for the
> construction of sewage facilities. Shall the proposed amendment be
> approved?

My confusion is over why the ballot measures are necessary (outside of the regular municipal government budget). My worry is that I might be voting to allow the creation of a slush fund.

For A (school districts): Are school districts completely distinct from municipal districts? Is school district debt separate from municipal debt, and if so (or even if not), who administers this debt?

Similarly for B: Why is this a special ballot initiative, why does sewer debt need a special exemption, who benefits, who administers, etc.?

Basically, I am realizing there's a lot I don't know. I tried asking friends, and no one I know knows the answer. I'm hoping someone can help me understand this.

-- Edit --

I found the information I was looking for here:

https://gothamist.com/news/schools-and-sewers-what-to-know-about-new-yorks-2023-ballot-proposals

Both of these ballot proposals are good for the state. I have checked the answer that was provided as correct, as this spurred me to look for ballot proposal opposition, and that led me to the Gothamist article.

Comment: This should be split into multiple questions as the ballot amendments are not related and will have different answers.

Comment: Hi ControlAltDel, welcome to Politics.SE! As with most other sites on Stack Exchange, you should try to avoid asking multiple questions at once. I would suggest you post a separate question for each ballot proposal or a general question regarding NYS constitutional debt limits. Note that ballot proposals are an essential part of all changes to the constitution of New York State (as voter approval is required by Article 19 thereof).

Comment: There are explainers on each question from Albany Law School but I'm having trouble opening the links right now. https://www.albanylaw.edu/news/government-law-center-fellows-break-down-ny-constitution-issues-ahead-election-day

Comment: @BrianZ Thanks for this I was able to open the link, and what is says is illuminating. But I still have questions: Why was the small city school district policy established in the first place? What was the reason for this? And as for the sewer exemption: it has a history, but how can I know if this still makes sense? This is all so opaque.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these proposals seem straightforward, though I can't judge the backstory.

For the first… for some reason the New York state constitution includes an article that limits how much debt a small city (one with less than 125,000 people) can accumulate for schools and school facilities. This may have been implemented to prevent small cities from monopolizing federal and state loans (meaning less funds available for districts in large cities), or it may have been implemented to benefit small cities by keeping school districts from incurring debt that the tax-base of the city can't support. School districts are semi-independent of the cities that contain them. Large cities will often have multiple school districts, while small cities may only have one that may even incorporate surrounding towns and rural areas.

Likewise for the second, the state constitution limits the amount that municipal areas can spend on infrastructure, but there is currently an exemption granted for sewage system improvement. That exemption is set to expire, and this proposal seeks to extend it for ten years. Infrastructure of this sort is also usually allocated to semi-independent districts (in this case, water and sewage districts), and the rule was (again) likely put into place to keep municipalities from outstripping their tax-base or monopolizing federal and state resources.

These proposals could both be good faith effort to meet civic infrastructure needs, but it's worth looking into who supports and opposes the bills to make sure someone isn't trying to finesse the system. Infrastructure is one of the easiest and most profitable areas for corruption, since few people can adequately judge how much money is actually needed for large projects of that sort.

Comment: Your advice to look for proposal adversaries led me to an article on Gothamist, which answered my questions (I've edited my question with this information. See above)